# Getting "AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader" while trying create users through rest api

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

i am trying create users in azure apim using put method through azure rest api the url looks like this
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/7xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/wbgintapim/users/test?api-version=2022-08-01

and authorization header is like

```
 Authorization  SharedAccessSignature integration&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
```

body is

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "Qwerty123$",
    "firstname": "test",
    "lastname": "apim"
}
```

i am getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader",
        "message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."
    }
}
```

can some help where I am doing wrong
i am taking key from here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, you are using incorrect authorisation header value.

Looking at the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest), Shared Access Signature authorization header is only supported when you are managing your Azure APIM instance directly. In this case, you should be using `https://{servicename}.management.azure-api.net` and not your current URL.

To fix this issue, either use `https://{servicename}.management.azure-api.net` URL. If you want to use Azure Resource Manager REST API, you would want to get a bearer token and use that for authorization like any other Azure RM REST API.